# Linear transformation is bijective if it has an inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, linear-transformations, pseudoinverse

$T : R^{n\times m}\to R^{m\times m}$,  $C \to (AC)^T$

I need to find the inverse of this linear transformation, when A is an invertible matrix... Can anyone help me with this problem?

I am asked to show that the transformation is bijective if A is inversible so I thought about using that a lin. transformation is bijective iff it has an inverse... maybe there is a better way

I realize that A has either a left or right inverse, and that both are a (n x m) matrix.

If B is the left inverse of A, I have figured that $S(X): B(X)^T$ is the inverse of T

Is that enough or do I also have to find a transformation assuming B is the right inverse of A?

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is invertible, it must be square, and $AA' = A'A = I$. Also the transformation $t$ that assigns a matrix its transpose, is invertible (just take the transpose again).

Comment: But doesn´t A have to be a (m x n) so that the (AC) multiplication is defined?

Comment: @Fryie ....and also for the (AC)^T to be an (m x m) matrix?

Comment: That's right. I think there must be a mistake in the question. More generally, a linear transformation from $R^{m\cdot n}$ to $R^{m\cdot m}$ cannot be invertible, since the two vector spaces don't have the same dimension. Unless $m = n$, of course.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will try using that m=n for T to have an inverse.